# Is it possible to use react hooks in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

In react documentation it says that the variable and the listener hook must be declared within the component but React native complains when I try to do that.

Is there any way to use the Hooks in React Native?
Or does anyone know if they are going to be implemented in the future ?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-hooks

Comment: See the thread, it says RN v0.59 is going to support React hooks: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21967

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of, though `useEffect` is not working. The current plan is to move to react 16.6 by 0.57.5 and allow people to opt in to using hooks with an option 0.57.5-alpha build. If you want to use hooks now:

1. Change your react dependency to `16.7.0-alpha` in *package.json*
2. Clone [react](https://github.com/facebook/react)
3. `cd react`
4. `yarn install`
5. `yarn build -- --type=RN_OSS`
6. copy `build/react-native` to your project's `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer` directory.

You can also use [this unofficial `react-native` build](https://github.com/csfrequency/react-native#0.57.4-hooks.1) with hooks already included. Just remember that `useEffect` is not working at all with react-native, so you're better off probably waiting. You can read more about this discussion on [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21967).

EDIT: Hooks are coming!!! They are live in React and have been confirmed as a feature shipping in React Native 0.59, you can even use the [current release candidate](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.59.0-rc.3)

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

React Hooks are part of the `0.59` release.

Quote from the `0.59` release notes:

> [React Hooks are part of this [0.59] release, which let you reuse stateful logic across components](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/03/12/releasing-react-native-059#hooks-are-here)

There's a quick overview of Hooks, to get you started:: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

React `16.8.0` is the first release to support Hooks. When upgrading, don’t forget to update all packages, including React DOM. React Native supports Hooks since the `0.59` release of `React Native`.

**No Breaking Changes**

Before we continue, note that Hooks are:

• **Completely opt-in.** You can try Hooks in a few components without rewriting any existing code. But you don’t have to learn or use Hooks
   right now if you don’t want to.

• **100% backwards-compatible.** Hooks don’t contain any breaking changes.

• **Available now**. Hooks are now available with the release of v16.8.0.

**Only Call Hooks from React Functions**

Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.
 Instead, you can:

1. Call Hooks from React function components
2. Call Hooks from custom Hooks

**Some Basic Hooks are mention below**

useState

useEffect

useContext

**Some Additional Hooks**

useReducer

useCallback

useMemo

useRef

useImperativeHandle

useLayoutEffect

useDebugValue

**For more information please read following document**

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html