# React Navigation support useEffect Hook? Error callback is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am writing the first applications in React Native. I'm using version 0.59. I imported the React-Navigation library and encountered the following problem:

I have a problem with the useEffect hook.When I next navigate to the component with useEffect I get following error : callback is not a function.

https://github.com/cassubianApp/react-navigation-test

it looks like the hook is calling, but right after that it gets a bug. Could this be a problem with my configuration or if React Navigation does not support hooks

Sorry for my english

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226655/is-it-possible-to-use-react-hooks-in-react-native), looks like hooks were only officially supported in react-native recently.

Comment: i have imported 0.59 react-native version.